# Command, shift, etc special keys not being recognized across multiple keyboards

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

I have multiple keyboards connected to my MacBook. When I send special modifier keys such as shift or command on one keyboard, that key is not being recognized when I press a key on a different keyboard. An example would be pressing shift on one keyboard then pressing K on another keyboard to get capital 'K'. However, this does not work. I end up with lowercase 'k'. How do I detect modifier keys across keyboards?